# How to write makefile to compile with -S and -c?

Tags: c, gcc, makefile

I have a source file `test.c` and its header `test.h`, a file `main.c` and the `makefile`. 
I want to set up my makefile so that it (1) compiles `test.c` to build an executable `test.o`, 
and (2) compiles `test.c` to print the assembly code to `test.s` using `-S` flag.

I have tried to set up the makefile as I thought would be correct, but this of course doesn't actually run the last `test.s` line.

```
FLAGS = -c -Wall
CC = gcc
ASM = -S

all : optimize
optimize: main.o test.o
    $(CC) main.o test.o -o optimize
main.o: main.c test.h
    $(CC) $(FLAGS) main.c
test.o: test.h test.c
    $(CC) $(FLAGS) test.c
test.s: test.h test.c
    $(CC) $(ASM) -Wall test.c
```

Can anyone tell me how I should have structured this differently, to create **both** test.s and test.o?

I tried to change the `optimize:` line and the following one to:

```
optimize: main.o test.o test.s
    $(CC) main.o test.o test.s -o optimize
```

but the linker gave an error `multiple definition of 'test'`.

Comment: How about `all: optimize test.s`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add test.s to the line that starts with `optimize:`.

What this does is add the rule `test.s` to the dependencies of the optimize line.

You could also add it to the all line, as suggested by Vaughn Cato.

It's important to know that there is a difference between the rule test.s and the file test.s

You can put anything you want as the name of the rule, but by convention you normally just use the filename.

Here's an example Makefile that will do what you want.  I put the dep under all so you can just `make asm` and I also changed the rule name to asm for clarity.

```
FLAGS = -c -Wall
CC = gcc
ASM = -S

all : optimize asm
optimize: main.o test.o
    $(CC) main.o test.o -o optimize
main.o: main.c test.h
    $(CC) $(FLAGS) main.c
test.o: test.h test.c
    $(CC) $(FLAGS) test.c
asm: test.h test.c
    $(CC) $(ASM) -Wall test.c -o test.s
```

Finally, because you seem a bit shaky on how Makefiles work, (I don't blame you honestly), I suggest reading this tutorial: http://mrbook.org/tutorials/make/

Comment: As mentioned in the (now updated) question, your first suggestions brings up further errors with multiple definitions

Comment: Not to both lines, just to the dependency line.  Remove from the second, not the first.

Comment: I updated the answer to include a sample Makefile, let me know if it works.

Comment: ok, thanks that works. Maybe add emphasis to **only that line** in your answer.

Comment: I updated my answer a few times for clarity.  Let me know if you understand everything a bit better.